# Xamarin.Forms: Cannot connect to database

Tags: sql, xamarin.forms

I have this database structure:

```
public class QRDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public QRDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<db_QRCODE_Type>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<db_QRCODE_Type>> GetQRCode()
    {
        return _database.Table<db_QRCODE_Type>().ToListAsync();
    }


    public Task<int> SaveQRCode(db_QRCODE_Type note)
    {
        if (note.ID != 0)
        {
            return _database.UpdateAsync(note);
        }
        else
        {
            return _database.InsertAsync(note);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DelteQRCode(db_QRCODE_Type note)
    {
        return _database.DeleteAsync(note);
    }
}
```

This uses this type:

```
public class db_QRCODE_Type
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; } // Identificator of column 
    public string firstName { get; set; } // firstname
    public string lastName { get; set; } // firstname
    public byte[] qrBytes { get; set; } //qr code in bytes 


}
```

Then, in the class where I need the DB I am doing this from the tutorial here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

```
static QRDatabase database;
    static string nameOfDB = "01db_qrs_q2go.db3";
    public static QRDatabase Database
    {
        get
        {
            if (database == null)
            {
                database = new QRDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), nameOfDB));
            }
            return database;
        }
    }
```

However, I am not quite sure how this works since I am never calling "Database" even though this is where the database is supposed to be initiliased.

Now, when I try to write to the database:

```
    db_QRCODE_Type entry = new db_QRCODE_Type();
    entry.firstName = entry_firstname.Text;
    entry.lastName = entry_lastname.Text;
    entry.qrBytes = qrCodeBytes;


    try
    {
        await database.SaveQRCode(entry);
    }
    catch
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("Etwas hat nicht funktioniert, bitte versuche es noch einmal. Fehlercode: DB_665h");
    }
```

It fails saying it is not set reference to an instance and goes into the catch block. I am doing everything as in the tutorial. Why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: in your third code block you are using "Database" instead of "QRDatabase"

Comment: Thank you, but it was actually just a type from copy pasting.. so taht wasnt it :(

Comment: please edit your post to fix it, otherwise it appears your code is completely broken.  The stack trace should tell you which specific line is causing the exception

Comment: It is fixed. It chrashes under await database.SaveQRCode(entry); This is also the first time I am actually trying to do anything with the database. the database object is not set an instance to a reference.

Comment: then you need to step through your code and determine why the db object is not getting set

Comment: In your Try/Catch you should call SaveQrCode on "Database" property, not on the field database

Comment: Geezus, THANK YOU! Please answer and Ill accept. This was driving my nuts. Maybe it would be better not to be so close in within the naming... anyway THANKS A LOT!